# C++ for loop variable lifetime is weird

Tags: c++, variables, scope, initialization, lifetime

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        int n;
        n++;
        printf("n : %d\n", n)'
    }
}
```

The output of the code is 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9. I'm wondering why the variable n in the for loop isn't initialized when the variable declaration is executed.

Comment: I dont know how exactly C++ works, but, with the experience that I had with C, maybe it is allocating in the same block of memory? try int n = 0.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're never initializing n to a specific value. C++ will not do this by default when you call `int n`. Instead, it just reserves an integer sized block of memory. So when you call `n++`, the program is just grabbing whatever value happens to be in that memory and incrementing it. Since you're doing this in quick succession and not creating new variables in between, it happens to be grabbing the same memory over and over. As @NicolasBuquet points out, compiler optimization may also be responsible for the consistency with which the same chunk of memory is picked.

If you were to assign a value to n, (i.e. `int n = 1;`) this behavior would go away because a specific value will be written to the chunk of memory assigned to n.

Comment: And I think it is due also to the optimizer: as your declare the same int variable at each iteration of your loop, I thnk the compiler optimized it and put the variable outside the loop rather than creating it at each step.

Comment: It makes just as much sense without that optimization, because nothing else is declared on the stack during each iteration, so the variable gets the same position on the stack each time.

Answer (score 1):

In C++, no variable is initialized with a default value; you must specify one explicitly should you find the need to do so.

The result of your code is really undefined; it is just pure luck that you are getting the numbers 1 through 9 in sequence. On some other machine or implementation of C++, you might get different results.

Comment: Many variables are initialized with default values.  Automatic variables that are built-in types are not automatically initialized.  Members of classes that are poorly written might not be automatically initialized.  However, you are correct that `n` in the example code is not initialized.

Comment: variables with static storage duration are value-initialized (i.e. zero-initialized for fundamental types)

Comment: lol, ok folks, you got me there. I stand corrected on both points.